# Get all users that the same post is not suggested to them with loopback

Tags: mongoose, loopback

Suppose I have below collections:
1- `users`
2- `posts`
3- `postSuggestion`

In `postSuggestion` I have `userId, postId, suggesterId`, now what I want to do is to take all users that post with id `12345` is not suggested for them.
What I tried so far is:

```
 getAllUsers(): Observable<any> {
   var currentUserId = this._postUserApi.getCurrentId();
   return this._http
     .get(`api/postsUsers?filter[where][id][neq]=`+currentUserId+`&filter[fields][id]=true&filter[fields][firstName]=true&filter[fields][lastName]=true`)
     .map((res: Response) => res.json())
     .catch(this.handleError);
 }
```

above function return all users except logged in user, but want to add one more condition to check that take those users that the same post is not suggested before for them.

Comment: 'take all users that post with id `12345` is not suggested for them' - can you explain this in detail ? Is `12345` post_id ?

Comment: @itssajan Yeah exactly, suppose userA view post (12345) then he want to suggest this post for some users, i need to take list of all users except (userA, and all other users that this post is suggested for them) something like this `(allUsers - [userA + users that this post is suggested for them before])`.

Answer (score 1):

From the api url your current looks like the following

```
filter:{
    where:{
      id:{
        neq: $currentUserId // your user id
      }
    },
    fields:{
      is: true,
      firstName: true,
      lastName: true,
    }
}
```

What you need is an additional filter. You can achieve this like the following

```
filter:{
    where:{
      and:[
        id:{ neq: $currentUserId },
        post_id: 12345
      ]
    },
    fields:{
      is: true,
      firstName: true,
      lastName: true,
    }
}
```

Comment: `post_id` is not inside `users`, instead of that i have another collection `postSuggestion` that contain the `userId, postId`

Comment: use the filter I have given inside `postSuggestion`

Comment: Query take data from `postUsers` collection, but you add a filter which is not related to the `postUsers` collection `(post_id: 12345)`, infect there is no any field like `post_id` inside this collection, so how it should know to consider `post_id: 12345`?

Comment: sorry my mistake, i meant `postId` in `postSuggestion` model

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I've never worked with mongoose, but if you have access to the database, you could try this query:

```
db.postSuggestion.aggregate([
    {$match: {
        suggesterId: {$ne: 2}, // suggesterId=2
        postId: {$ne: 1} // postId=1
    }},
    // remove dups userId will become _id
    {$group: {
        _id: "$userId"
    }},
    // recover user data
    {$lookup: {
        from: 'user',
        localField: '_id',
        foreignField: 'userId',
        as: 'user'
    }},
    // unwind user array
    {$unwind: '$user'},
    // project user name and id only
    {$project: {
        _id: 0,
        'user.userId': 1,
        'user.name': 1
    }}
])
```

By the way, I don't recommend MongoDB to be used as a relational database, but if you want to continue using it, then I strongly advice you to change your data model, keep a single collection and work updating documents, your queries will be less messy.

Bonus: [Robomongo](https://robomongo.org/) is a free MongoDB GUI and it's very useful to test your queries.

Answer (score 0):

If you want some solutions , you must provide what you are using, so we can have a common ground to discuss. If you want a conceptual idea,

The answer should be

`not yet receive suggestion users = <all users> - <select userId from postSuggestion where postSuggestion.postId = 12345> - currentUserId`